# Absolute path with string variable

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception, absolute-path

PLEASE help me to understand what is going on here:

**my code:**

```
import java.io.File;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = "‪d:\\downloads\\testfile.mp3";

        File file1 = new File(name);
        System.out.println(file1.getAbsolutePath());

        File file = new File("d:\\downloads\\testfile.mp3");        
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

**The output**:

```
J:\Louw\Programming\PathTest\‪d:\downloads\testfile.mp3
d:\downloads\testfile.mp3
```

**Question:**
Why would the `String` variable produce a different Absolutepath than typing the string directly with new File object? (Obviously the first output also throws a "FileNotFound" exception if trying to use later).

my Eclipse java development environment is:

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Neon.2 Release (4.6.2)
Build id: 20161208-0600

Please assist.

Comment: Are you sure that first part (`J:\Louw\Programming\PathTest\‪`) isn't the path you're running it from? Add a `System.out.println()` at the top of the `main` function to make sure.

Comment: You and we will get to know more if you print a caption for each line of output, for example `System.out.println("file1: " + file1.getAsolutePath());`.

Comment: It's an aside, the `File` class is outdated, consider `java.nio.file.Path` and friends instead.

Comment: Ole V.V - thank you ... I did as you suggested and the output is: File1: J:\Louw\Programming\PathTest\‪d:\downloads\testfile.mp3  File2: d:\downloads\testfile.mp3.  I am still confused?

Comment: Scovetta - yes it is the 'working' directory of the project .. but why is it appending it in front of the Absolutepath?

Comment: I am getting curious, @LouwPieters, did any of the answers work for you? If so, please also consider accepting one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I am not 100 % sure whether this is the correct explanation, but I believe it is consistent, so I also believe that it is worth for you to check.

When I copy your code into my Eclipse, your string `name` begins with a character with Unicode value 8234 (202A hexadecimal). This character is not printed, so the two strings look the same, but they are not. The mentioned character is not it the string that you pass when constructing the second `File` object. On [fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202a/index.htm) the character is called “left-to-right embedding”, I don’t know what this means.

It would make sense that such a character in front of `d:\\` would cause Java not to recognize the string as an absolute path name and therefore take it as a relative one, relative to your working directory.

It remains to be determined whether that character is in your source file too or only has crept in on Stack Overflow or in my copy-paste operation.

If the 8234 is indeed the culprit: in my Eclipse I can delete it with backspace as any other character, and everything works as expected. Failing that, you can always delete a sequence of characters containing at least the `"` before and the `d` after and type them again.

Where that char may come from, I have no good idea. It sounds unlikely that you should have typed Alt-202A on your keyboard without knowing you had done so.

Comment: Absolutely correct sir - thank you. Not sure how this 'unprintable' character slipped in there ... but I deleted it and all is working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, and is doing what you expect.  It's printing `‪d:\downloads\testfile.mp3` twice.

Either something in how you execute your program is printing `J:\Louw\Programming\PathTest\` with no newline to stdout before running your program, or you're seeing the system prompt and interpreting it as output.

Comment: Hello. no it isn't something else printing the working directory path ... as demonstrated when I println "File1: "+ file1.getAbsolutePath(). The program you see at the top is the whole program ... just as a test.

Answer (score 1):

You have a strange non-printable Unicode character at the start of your `name` String.  The second instance of the string looks the same, but doesn't include that character.  Paste the second string over the top of your first string and the problem will go away.

Comment: Yes this was the problem. How that happened - not sure but it works now that I got rid of that 'strange character'. Thank you!